# Can I stop JS location.href without a popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, location, href

I want to build a JS external script ( tag) which stops code (which usually isn't mine) like location.href from happening without the use of a popup.
I tried things like:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
 window.stop();
 event.stopImmediatePropagation();
 event.preventDefault();
 location.href = '#';  
 });
```

but nothing seemed to help.
again, I need it without the use of the: return "are you sure?"
maybe a different callback?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Not possible. Being able to stop navigation without user input would break the way browsing works.

Comment: I have the same feeling. On example in Firefox they deliberately block overriding window.location.href for security reasons. See [this bug in bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=736694).

Comment: Actually it's possible. Otherwise, sites asking you if you want "to leave and lose changes" wouldn't exist. The beforeunload event exists and it catches even if you close the window without surfing away.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to use `onbeforeunload` to confirm navigating away is to just return the string of the message you want to have shown. [MDN has this to say](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload).

> The function should assign a string value to the returnValue property of the Event object and return the same string

So your `onbeforeunload` function for the behavior you ask for would just be (same as binding it with jquery, especially since onbeforeunload does not support multiple event listeners like other events do)

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you sure?";
};
```

But ironically, Firefox doesn't support this for security purposes.

> Note that in Firefox 4 and later the returned string is not displayed to the user. See [bug 588292](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292).

**Edit:** I read more of the bug report. The main reason they site for this decision is: "1. Remove the site-supplied text, since this is a security issue (untrusted text in browser dialogs)". I wonder how they feel about an `alert`?

Most modern browsers (Chome, IE 9+ or earlier, and Opera, I know for sure) will ignore anything you try to do in an `onbeforeunload` function other than returning a string for display. This is to prevent hijacking the users browser, opening popups, overriding navigation attempts by pointing the user another, possibly malicious domain, etc.

**Edit 2:** I was apparently incorrect. Only *some* things are disallowed in `onbeforeunload`, they just happen to mainly be the types of things you tried in your sample code, having to do with event propagation and page navigation. From [deep in the comments](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292#c97) of that FF bug report, user oyasumi posts a link to this jsFiddle with a work around for displaying custom text to FF 4+ users: http://jsfiddle.net/ecmanaut/hQ3AQ/ So apparently calling `alert()` is still allowed, even in `onbeforeunload`, which hilariously is doing exactly what the was original reason for the 'bug' "fix": displaying custom text in a browser/application/OS/official-looking dialog.

Answer (score -1):

did you try to use "return false" ?
Also you should have the event sent to your function.
here is an example where you can prevent from a button click and hyper link

```
<input type="button" value="click me" />
<a href="www.google.com"> google </a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/juTtG/143/

Comment: in jQuery calling return false is like calling both e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() .. as explained by the creator of JQuery John Resig: http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg71371.html and http://jquery.10927.n7.nabble.com/Any-benefit-to-using-event-preventDefault-over-quot-return-false-quot-to-cancel-out-an-href-click-td102980.html

Comment: return false (without the "" offcourse) in this case, prints "return flase" in the popup, it's weird, but this is what happens, so it isn't good for me. And I don't have a input button or a a href, I have a Flash (not mine) that calls a JS method that does the location.href='url' . But thanks for the direction

Comment: ops sorry the return false was a left out